# How to color serial IO?

Tags: terminal, serial-port

Is it possible to activate colors, e.g. for `PS1` or `git` output for a terminal that is only connected over serial? What options have to be activated?

Comment: This is typically done with terminal specific escape sequences.

Comment: For example? I tried to get my normal PS1 coloring done via serial and it only printed garbage and no color at all. I would really like to know what actually happens there.